# Why does this graph route repeat

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, graph-databases

I have been learning graph algorithms in Python, and am wondering why I am getting a repeated path in results.

This is my code

```
from collections import defaultdict

our_graph = defaultdict(list)


def run_graph():
    print('Creating Graph...')
    add_edges("London", "Barcelona")
    add_edges("Barcelona", "Madrid")
    add_edges("Madrid", "Ottawa")
    add_edges("Madrid", "Berlin")
    add_edges("London", "Ottawa")

    print('\nOur Graph:')
    print(our_graph)

    print('\nEdges:')
    print(list_edges())

    print('\nTesting Paths To Invalid Nodes:')
    print(find_all_paths("LDN", "Ottawa"))
    print(find_all_paths("London", "X"))

    print('\nTesting Paths To Valid Nodes:')
    print(find_all_paths("London", "Ottawa"))
    print('---')
    print(find_all_paths("London", "Berlin"))


def add_edges(a, b):
    our_graph[a].append(b)
    our_graph[b].append(a)


def list_edges():
    edges = []
    for node in our_graph:
        for next_node in our_graph[node]:
            edges.append((node, next_node))
    return edges


def find_all_paths(start, end, path=[]):
    # If there isn't a node with that name
    if our_graph[start] == [] or our_graph[end] == []:
        return 'Can\'t find nodes ' + start + " " + end
    else:
        # create a path
        path = path + [start]
        # If start node is the end
        if start == end:
            return [path]
        paths = []
        newpaths = []
        # For each node
        for node in our_graph[start]:
            # If node not already in saved path
            if node not in path:
                # Search the paths of that new node
                newpaths = find_all_paths(node, end, path)
            # Append new path to paths
            for newpath in newpaths:
                paths.append(newpath)
        return paths


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_graph()
```

The result I get from `print(find_all_paths("London", "Berlin"))`

is

```
[['London', 'Barcelona', 'Madrid', 'Berlin'], ['London', 'Ottawa', 'Madrid', 'Berlin'], ['London', 'Ottawa', 'Madrid', 'Berlin']]
```

As you can see the route London-Ottawa-Madrid-Berlin is repeated. Can you explain why?

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
if node not in path:
    # Search the paths of that new node
    newpaths = find_all_paths(node, end, path)
# Append new path to paths
for newpath in newpaths:
    paths.append(newpath)
```

if `node` is already in `path`, the old `newpaths` will be used. All you need is to move the for loop under the if statement:

```
if node not in path:
    # Search the paths of that new node
    newpaths = find_all_paths(node, end, path)
    # Append new path to paths
    for newpath in newpaths:
        paths.append(newpath)
```

or:

```
if node not in path:
    # Search the paths of that new node
    paths += find_all_paths(node, end, path)
```

Also, I would recommend using `defaultdict(set)` instead of lists.

Comment: Thanks! Any reason you'd use a set instead of a list?

Comment: it is possible to have duplicate elements in a list, but not in a set